# Show social action sheet in ionic/ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there a way to show a social action sheet like this in ionic/ionic 2? I'd like to add social buttons there.

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613918/using-social-sharing-cordova-ionic-plugin-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the [Social Sharing Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin). I have used it in the past and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic provides the social sharing capability using Cordova social sharing plugin : [$cordovaSocialSharing](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/), and the plugin can be installed via:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

You can have a look at ngCordova page for examples.